# How to get without "default.aspx" url?

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, asp.net-2.0, global-asax

I implemented a following code in Global.asax file of my web application.

```
void Application_BeginRequest()
{

    string rule = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("WwwRule");

    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    if (context.Request.HttpMethod != "GET" || context.Request.IsLocal)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (context.Request.PhysicalPath.EndsWith(".aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        string url = context.Request.Url.ToString();

        if (!url.Contains("://www.") && rule == "add")
        {
            string url = context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("://", "://www.");
            context.Response.Redirect(url);
        }
    }
}
```

When I am running above code it works as follows

**example.com** redirects to **www.example.com/default.aspx**

**www.example.com** redirects to **www.example.com**

**http://www.example.com/** redirects to **http://www.example.com/**

last two conditions works very well. But the first condition did'nt works well because its adding "default.aspx" in the URL which I am not intrested in.

Can anyone please tell me how to make it as below

**example.com** should redirects to **http://www.example.com**

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that you are (attempting towards) doing url-rewriting instead of actual redirection.

Comment: nope I don't think its URL rewriting?? I just want that it should not add default.aspx in case if somebody is requesting like example.com/search.aspx then it can redirect to http://www.example.com/search.aspx

Comment: I am just concern about default.aspx ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the Request.Url is appending default.aspx because that's the page actually being served at the time (IIS makes this transparent to you because it's one of the default pages).

When you make your new URL that you're going to redirect, add another .Replace("/default.aspx", "") to the end of it. So...

```
string url = context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("://", "://www.").Replace("/default.aspx", "");
```

Comment: That won't work properly in all situations. Although given a very unlikely situation, but it will change "example.com/default.aspxfolder/file" into "www.example.comfolder/file".

Comment: @Guffa I agree, but simplicity is the point of my answer so that the asker will grasp what is happening in the most basic way and then can expand it as needed. :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the /default.aspx is added before the request reaches the BeginRequest event. If you want to remove it, you have to actually remove it:

```
void Application_BeginRequest() {
    string rule = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("WwwRule");

    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    if (context.Request.HttpMethod != "GET" || context.Request.IsLocal) {
        return;
    }

    if (context.Request.PhysicalPath.EndsWith(".aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        string url = context.Request.Url.ToString();

        if (!url.Contains("://www.") && rule == "add") {
            url = url.Replace("://", "://www.");
            if (url.EndsWith("/default.aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
               url = url.Substring(0, url.Length - 13);
            }
            context.Response.Redirect(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your webconfig with below code:it solve my same problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="default.aspx Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*\/)*default\.aspx$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" negate="true" pattern="^POST$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```